# Matlab question: fixing the scale of Y axis in hist

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I want to draw several histograms. But I want the Y axis to be fixed, like from 1000 to 1 by 100. How can I specify them。

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```
%# some data
X = randn(1000,3);
nbins = 10;

%# compute frequencies and bins
%#[count,bins] = hist(X, nbins);
count = zeros(10,size(X,2));
bins = zeros(10,size(X,2));
for i=1:size(X,2)
    [count(:,i),bins(:,i)] = hist(X(:,i),nbins);
end

%# show histograms
for i=1:size(X,2)
    subplot(1,size(X,2),i)
    bar(bins(:,i), count(:,i),'hist')
    set(gca, 'YTick',0:100:4000, 'YLim',[0 400])
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `axis` command is what you're looking for. You specify the `[XMIN XMAX YMIN YMAX]`. This example will have all histograms capped at a value of `5`. Also, you're asking a bunch of questions about MATLAB today without seemingly doing any research. Please ask a search engine and show that you've at least tried something.

```
clf;
subplot(1,2,1); hist(rand(1,10)); axis([0 1 0 5]);
subplot(1,2,2); hist(rand(1,10)); axis([0 1 0 5]);
```